# Kendo Treeview - Disable all child nodes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where I have a kendo treeview with checkboxes and have to disable the child nodes when the parent check box is checked.

My treeview is bound to a heirarchical data model from through MVC model binding.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                  .Name("TreeViewModel")
                  .Checkboxes(true)
                  .CheckboxTemplateId("treeview-template")
                  .ExpandAll(true)
                  .HighlightPath(true)
                  .BindTo(Model.TreeViewData)
                  .DragAndDrop(false)
                  .LoadOnDemand(false)
```

And my checkbox template looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="Addnode('#: item.text #', '#: item.id #', this.checked)" id ="#: item.id #" />
```

I am trying to get the list of child nodes for the checked node, but havent progressed much. In the AddNode function I use

```
    var dataSource = treeview.dataSource;
    var dataItem = dataSource.get(id);
    var node = treeview.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
```

to get the selected node, but node.hasChildren returns undefined and I dont seem to find a solution to get a list of child nodes for this one.

I have tried the JS fiddle here [Js Fiddle](http://dojo.telerik.com/oHAH)

Can someone help me out here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following JavaScript code:

```
$("#treeview").on("change", ":checkbox", function(e) {
    // Get reference to the Tree View
    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

    // Get the node owning the checked checkbox
    var current = $(e.target).closest("li.k-item");

    // Enable or Disable any child items depending if current item is checked or not  
    treeview.enable($(".k-item", current), !e.target.checked);
});
```

Your code modified here : http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/akoYU